# How to split each value in separate rows and sort?

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to convert a text file but it seems to be a little bit hard for me to organize it as I intend.

The file looks like as below.

```
(0,{35=9000.0, 36=9000.0, 33=9000.0, 34=9000.0})
```

I want to reorganize it as follows

```
0 33 9000.0
0 34 9000.0
0 35 9000.0
0 36 9000.0
```

Since I am quite new to shell I need your help to achieve my issue.
I want the items to be sorted by values inside of `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here solution in Perl:

```
cat b.txt 
(0,1,{35=9000.0, 36=9000.0, 33=9000.0, 34=9000.0})

perl -lne '$_=~/^\(([\d\,\.]+)\s*\{(.*)\}\)$/; @first=split /[,\s]/, $1; @second=split /,\s/, $2; map{($k, $v) = split "=", $_; $h{$k}=$v} @second; foreach $k (sort keys(%h)) { print join(" ", @first), " $k ",$h{$k}; }' b.txt
0 1 33 9000.0
0 1 34 9000.0
0 1 35 9000.0
0 1 36 9000.0
```

(Of course this Perl program will be much easier to read if use more that one line and if I know how to give meaning names to variables)

Answer (score 1):

GNU ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[,=]' '{ gsub(/[({}) ]/,"",$0); for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1); 
                asorti(a,b); for(k in a) print $1,k,a[k] }' file
```

- `-F'[,=]'` - field separator
- `gsub(/[({}) ]/,"",$0)` - removing unnecessary characters
- `for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1)` - collecting pairs of values into array `a`
- `asorti(a,b)` - sort the array `a` by keys

---

The output:

```
0 33 9000.0
0 34 9000.0
0 35 9000.0
0 36 9000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For every line of input, `$n` <= decimal value prior to leading comma.
2. hash `%h` whose keys are number to the left of `=` and values on the right.
3. then numerically sort the keys and print the `$n`, key, corresp. value.
4. `$,` = `OFS` <= `$"` = Output List Separator, which is space by default.

---

```
perl -lne '$,=$";
   ($n, %h) = ( /^\((\d+),/, /(\d+)=([^,}]+)/g );
   print $n, $_, $h{$_} for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h;
' yourfile
```

---

## Results:

```
0 33 9000.0
0 34 9000.0
0 35 9000.0
0 36 9000.0
```